# NextJS - getStaticPaths - Paths seems not bound to one of the params

Tags: javascript, next.js, fallback, getstaticpaths

My Next.js app's pages are provided by an API, each with a uri_prefix and a uri.
The uri_prefix is mandatory, and can be `c` or `s` for now. But any letter could be chosen in the end.

It's a pretty simple structure :

```
pages
   |-[prefix]
   |     |
   |     |-[slug]
```

The [slug].jsx page that handles it uses ISG.

So far, the getStaticPath fallback was set to true, so that if an admin creates new pages `(eg. {uri_prefix : c, uri : newpage1} & {uri_prefix : s, uri : newpage2})` in the backoffice, ISG generates the static `/c/newpage1` and `/s/newpage2` file when they are first triggered.

But once generated, trying alt url such as `/x/newpage` or `/whatever/newpage` also fires up the page, which is somewhat unexpected (and unwanted). Reading the doc, I thought it would allow only existing prefixes.

Setting fallback to false forbids unwanted urls but also requires a new build of the app, which is not convenient.

I'd like to have `/c/newpage1` or `/s/newpage2` rendered, but not `/c/newpage2` nor `/s/newpage1` (nor `/somethingelse/newpage*` of course). Each page associated with it's own prefix only.

Did I misunderstood how the fallback works ?

Is ther an obvious mistake in the code or is there another way to achieve ISG for new pages without whole build while forbidding unwanted urls ?

Here is the [slug].jsx page :

```
import Layout from '@/components/Layout';
import SmallCard from '@/components/SmallCard';
import {useRouter} from 'next/router';

export default function src({products, seo}) {

  const router = useRouter();
  if(router.isFallback) {
    return (
      <h1>Loading new page...</h1>
    )
  }

  return (
    products ? (
      <Layout title={seo[0].title} description={seo[0].description}>
        <div>
          <div className='container-fluid my-5'>
            <div className="row justify-content-center">
              <h1>{seo[0].h1}</h1>
            </div>
            <div className="row justify-content-center">
              {products.map(
                (product)=>(
                  <SmallCard product = {product}/>
                )
              )}
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </Layout>
    ) : (
      <Layout title={seo[0].title} description={seo[0].description}>
        <h1>{seo[0].h1}</h1>
        <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: seo[0].content_front}}/>
      </Layout>
    )
  )
}

export async function getStaticPaths() {

  const resPages = await fetch(`${process.env.API_BASE_URL}/path/to/pagesapi`);
  const pages = await resPages.json();
  const paths = pages.map((page) => ({
      params: {
        prefix: page.uri_prefix,
        slug: page.uri
      },
    }))

    return {
        paths,
        fallback: true
  };
}

export async function getStaticProps({ params: { slug } }) {
  const resPages = await fetch(`${process.env.API_BASE_URL}/path/to/pagesapi`);
  const pages = await resPages.json();
  const seo=pages.filter(page=> page.uri == slug);

  if(seo[0].src) {
    const src=seo[0].src;
  
    // get products
    const resProducts = await fetch(`${process.env.API_BASE_URL_LEGACY}${src}`);
    var products = await resProducts.json();
  } else {
    var products = null
  }

    return {
        props: {
            products,
            seo
        },
        revalidate:60,
    };
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can explicitly trigger a 404 page in your `getStaticProps` for undesired paths by returning `return { notFound: true }` when the `prefix` doesn't match `c` or `s`. You should be able to access the `prefix` value from the `params` passed to it.

Comment: @juliomalves Thanks for replying.
Your suggestion could have been a lead, but ```/s/newpage``` is still generated when only ```/c/newpage``` should, according to the prefix set.
I've edited the question, trying to make it clearer.

Comment: You can also trigger a 404 page if products is `null`. Ensures you only display a page when there's valid data.